# How can I return a summation of the results of MB51 instead of the row-by-row transactions?

Tags: sap-erp

I am using SAP GUI for Windows (SAP NetWeaver; 730 Final Release, Version 7300.3.15.1085), SAP ERP, and I need to find a faster way to do part of my routine. I use the form `MB51` along with some criteria to find all transactions I need. Then, I select the `Quantity in UnE` column and hit the sigma (Add Up Values) symbol at the top. This gives me the sum total of all rows at the bottom.

The goal is to simplify this process. I want to be able to add in the material, the plant, the reference, and the document header texts and just return the sum of all rows. I literally only need the final sum and nothing else. Does anyone know of a form in SAP that can help me do this? Or does anyone know of a way to customize `MB51` so that I achieve my desired output?

Comment: not sure if you can do this yourself, but often relatively simple requirements like this are solved with SAP queries (transaction SQ01). You will need to know the underlying tables involved in your requirement. If there is a SAP support team available to you I would recommend to contact them about your request.

Comment: The version number you quote appears to be a GUI version (and an outdated and unsupported one at that) which is mostly irrelevant for this case. Are you sure you're looking for programming solution - do you have the permission to develop anything in the system at all?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a Dirk's proposal to use SAP Query, you can consider creating [SAP transaction variant](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Transaction+Variant+-+A+Step+by+Step+Guide+for+Creation) and running it in a [background mode](https://blogs.sap.com/2010/01/04/how-to-create-a-dynamic-variant-and-setup-batch-job-with-dynamic-variant/).

This allows executing a transaction with the specified parameters (including summation) periodically and [sending results to email](https://blogs.sap.com/2010/02/25/how-to-email-output-from-background-jobs/).

It looks like you lack development permissions on the system, so this can be simplest way for acquiring a MB51 sum. Besides permissions, your task also requires knowledge of MB51 tables and their relations.

Comment: Ok it looks like I don't have the permission to open SHD0. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a layout variant and create a variant for the selection screen with the layout variant. You can also hide unused fields with the selection variant.

Comment: Could you help me get started? How would I do this? I looked around on all the button on the results page of MB51 and I couldn't find anything called a layout variant.